# Formula to calculate $(1n)+(2(n-1))+(3(n-2)+(4(n-3)) ...$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How would I go about calculating something like $(1\times4)+(2\times3)+(3\times2)+(4\times1)$? It is the equivalent of $(4+3+2+1)+(3+2+1)+(2+1)+(1)$.

Comment: To help connect the idea of combinations to the sum: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CmhIs.gif

Answer (score 0):

You may prove by induction on $n$ that
$$1\cdot n+ 2\cdot(n-1)+\ldots+(n-1)\cdot 2+n\cdot 1=\sum_{k=1}^{n} k\cdot(n+1-k) =\binom{n+2}{3}$$
holds. In your case, $n=4$, then answer is so given by $\binom{6}{3}=\color{red}{20}$.

Comment: @SimpleArt: that was just a typo, now fixed.

Comment: Say, I want to use this [image][1] to do the proof, but I can't make the connection to the product sum, it only makes sense with $1+(1+2)+(1+2+3)+\dots$.  Wondering if you could make the connection more clear. (and how to make links in comments) (credit picture from: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/8846/proofs-without-words/8847#8847)

[1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CmhIs.gif

Comment: @SimpleArt: any point in the yellow triangle is identified by two distinct points in the blue row. If the last row of the yellow triangle is made by $n$ circles, it follows that $1+2+3+\ldots+n = \binom{n+1}{2}$, since the length of the blue row is $n+1$.

Comment: Yes, I'm very aware of that, but I can't quite get the connection to $1\cdot n+2\cdot(n-1)+\dots$.

Comment: $1\cdot n+\ldots + n\cdot 1$ equals $$(n+\ldots+1)+((n-1)+\ldots+1)+\ldots+1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\binom{k+1}{2}$$

Comment: hence the result follows from the Hockey stick identity (http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two expressions you write are equivalent.  If you want to calculate that type of sum/product quickly for a similar longer expression, so you can find an explicit formula.  In your example, you go from 1 to 4, so let's call 4=n.

Then your expression $= \Sigma_{i=1}^n i(n-i+1) = \Sigma_{i=1}^n (i(n+1)- i^2) = (n+1) \Sigma_{i=1}^n i - \Sigma_{i=1}^n i^2 = (n+1) * n(n+1)/2 - n(n+1)(2n+1)/6 = n(n+1)(n+2)/6$

So when $n=4$, we get 4*5*6/6=20, which we know is correct.  But we can also plug in larger values of $n$ and get the answer instantly.

Answer (score 0):

So, from your saying
$$=>\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i(i+1)}{2}$$
$$=>\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^2 + i}{2}$$
$$=>n(\frac{n + 1}{4}) + \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}$$
$$=>\frac{n(n+1)(2n+4)}{12}$$
$$=>\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}$$